# Float(s) lost in table

Tags: tables, floats

Here is my MWE. I have 4 files here: My **analysis00.tex**, my **preamble.tex** (well part of that file anyway), my **toc.tex**, and my **chapter00.tex** (well part of that as well). I have left out my **chapter01.tex** as it is irrelevant for this discussion.

**I just edited this to add everything in one document** and upon doing so, I still am getting the same error message.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[left=2.50cm,right=2.50cm,top=2.50cm,bottom=2.75cm]    {geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd,amsbsy,array,color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,framed,latexsym,multicol,pstricks,slashed,xcolor}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=black
```

}

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\setenumerate[1]{label=(\alph*)}
\setenumerate[2]{label=(\roman*)}

\usepackage[amsmath,framed,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\usepackage{changes}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\section}[frame]
{\normalfont}
{\filcenter
\footnotesize
\enspace SECTION \thesection\enspace}
{8pt}
{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremsymbol{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
\theoreminframepreskip{0pt}
\theoreminframepostskip{0pt}
\theoremframepreskip{1cm}
\theoremframepostskip{1cm}
\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
\psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,linecolor=black]}
\newshadedtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Logic, Set Theory, Functions, and Relations.}

\begin{proof}
The proof makes use of the following truth table.
$\,$   
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|c|c||c|c|}
        \hline
        $P$ & $Q$ & $P \Rightarrow Q$ & $\neg P$ & $\neg Q$ & $(\neg      Q) \Rightarrow (\neg P)$ & $Q \Rightarrow P$ \\
        \hline
        $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ \\
        \hline
        $T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $F$ & $T$ \\
        \hline
        $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$& $T$ & $F$ \\
        \hline
        $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\emph{Truth Table for $P \Rightarrow Q$, $(\neg Q)                \Rightarrow (\neg P),$ and $Q \Rightarrow P.$}}
\end{table}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Whenever I compile, I get the error:

```
Float(s) lost. lnclude{chapter0}
```

Not sure what to do here. Thanks.

Comment: please fix your examples so that people can reproduce the error, but presumably you have defined `proof` to be some kind of boxed environment that can not contain a float.  Since you refer to the table in the running text as "the following table" it shod not be in a `table` environment at all, as the only reason for using `table` is to allow latex to move the content to help with page breaking. Just use `tabular` directly.

Comment: also don't load `etex` unless you have an old (pre 2015) latex, and `\center` should be `\centering`

Comment: Drop *everything* unrelated to this problem, even the packages you load - if the problem is replicates *without* some package, then remove it. Also, try to make it easy for your audience to work on the problem - don't provide separate files when you can contain everything in a single file. Sure, it doesn't represent your setup exactly, but you're here for free help, so play along...

Comment: Sorry please forgive me for sounding stupid or ignorant but I finally (sorry it took so long) deleted the etex, and I took out the table command but now I get the following error: package caption Error: \caption outside float. \caption

Comment: this is probably just a typo. but in the question you show a file name `chapter00` rather than `chapter0`.  if that's really its name, then it wouldn't be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a more reasonable example document, then commented out the parts you do not want as you apparently do not want a floating table here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,framed,pstricks}
\usepackage[amsmath,framed,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremsymbol{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
\theoreminframepreskip{0pt}
\theoreminframepostskip{0pt}
\theoremframepreskip{1cm}
\theoremframepostskip{1cm}
\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
\psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,linecolor=black]}
\newshadedtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  The proof makes use of the following truth table.
% $\,$ ??? :-) 
%      \begin{table}[h!]
%  \centering
\begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|c|c||c|c|}
      \hline
          $P$ & $Q$ & $P \Rightarrow Q$ & $\neg P$ & $\neg Q$ & $(\neg Q) \Rightarrow (\neg P)$ & $Q \Rightarrow P$ \\
      \hline
          $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ \\
      \hline
          $T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $F$ & $T$ \\
      \hline
          $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$& $T$ & $F$ \\
      \hline
          $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ \\
      \hline
      \end{tabular}
\end{center}

%\caption
{\emph{Truth Table for $P \Rightarrow Q$, $(\neg Q) \Rightarrow (\neg P),$ and $Q \implies P.$}}

%\end{table}
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much David! I really appreciate it!!! That is just what I wanted.